# 422 Unprocessable Entity Error after fetch POST request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch

I'm receiving a 422 Unprocessable Entity, invalid inputs error when making a fetch POST request. This resulted in an empty object {} in my Request Payload.

I've done the following checks. Please take a look and kindly guide me in the right direction.

• checked post-routes

```
router.post(
      '/',
      [
        check('location').not().isEmpty(),
        check('caption').not().isEmpty()
      ],
      postsControllers.createPost
    );
```

• checked posts-controller, extracting correct attributes from body

```
const { userId, location, caption } = req.body;

const createdPost = new Post({
  userId,
  location,
  imageUrl: 'abc.jpeg',
  caption,
})
```

• checked if managing userId in front-end auth-context

```
// auth-context
export const AuthContext = createContext({
  isLoggedIn: false,
  userId: null,
  login: () => {},
  logout: () => {}
});

// App.js
const login = useCallback((uid) => {
  setIsLoggedIn(true);
  setUserId(uid);
}, []);

const logout = useCallback(() => {
  setIsLoggedIn(false);
  setUserId(null);
}, []);
```

• checked if user property is mapped to user object in signup and login

```
// signup action of users-controllers
res.status(201).json({ user: createdUser.toObject({ getters: true })});

// login action of users-controllers
res.json({ message: 'Logged in!', user: existingUser.toObject({ getters: true })});
```

• checked if url, request, body and headers are included when sending request in new post

```
// New Post
<Formik
  initialValues={‌{ location: '', caption: ''}}
  validationSchema={validationSchema}
  onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    try {
      fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/posts', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
    userId: auth.userId,
    email: values.email,
    password: values.password
      })
    )
  history.push('/');
  } catch (err) {}
}}
```

[image]

Comment: `[
        check('location').not().isEmpty(),
        check('caption').not().isEmpty()
]` Your body don't need to have these fields?

Comment: Thanks @PedroMutter. Fresh eyes to solve the issue. I appreciate it!